# How to prove a*b*c=a*(b*c) in Coq?

Tags: coq, induction, coqide

Im trying to prove the above question. I have been given a definition of an induction:

```
Definition nat_ind 
  (p : nat -> Prop)
  (basis : p 0)
  (step : forall n, p n -> p (S n)) :
    forall n, p n := fix f n :=
      match n return p n with
      | 0 => basis
      | S n => step n (f n)
      end.
```

This is my attempt, but don't know how to finish

```
Goal forall a b c, a * b * c = a * (b * c).
Proof. 
 apply nat_ind.
  - intros a b c. revert a.
    apply (nat_ind (fun a => a * b * c = a * (b * c))); simpl.
    + reflexivity.
    + intros. f_equal. intros.
```

Answer (score 1):

After your very first `nat_ind` invocation, if you look at your goal, you see that Coq did not do the right thing at all!

```
______________________________________(1/3)
forall a b c : nat, a * b * c = a * (b * c)
______________________________________(2/3)
nat ->
(forall a b c : nat, a * b * c = a * (b * c)) ->
forall a b c : nat, a * b * c = a * (b * c)
______________________________________(3/3)
nat
```

What happened here is that it made a guess for your motive `p`, and decided to unify it with `fun (_ : nat) => <YOUR_WHOLE_GOAL>`, a function which given any `nat` would give your goal... Yes, this is silly!

One way to nudge it into doing the induction on `a` is by explicitly forcing it to do so, with:

`apply nat_ind with (n := a)`

(where the `n` matches the name used in your definition of `nat_ind`)

After this, you get the much more reasonable goals:

```
______________________________________(1/2)
forall b c : nat, 0 * b * c = 0 * (b * c)
______________________________________(2/2)
forall n : nat,
(forall b c : nat, n * b * c = n * (b * c)) ->
forall b c : nat, S n * b * c = S n * (b * c)
```

where indeed `a` has been replaced by `0` and `S n` respectively.

[EDIT: I guess this does not quite answer your question as you had gotten your way to the same point with the second induction call...]

To solve your goal, it will help a lot to have a property about distributivity of multiplication over addition:

```
forall n m p, (n + m) * p = n * p + m * p
```

All of these, as well as what you're trying to prove, already exists in Coq. Is this homework? Are you just training?